# How to view commits from one day only in a pretty format in git?

Tags: git, git-log

I'd like to view commit history in the console that:

1. Is only from one day, e.g. May 14,
2. Each row contains only: a) commit message, b) commit SHA, c) author.

I've tried `git log --after="May 13" --before="May 15" --pretty=oneline`

but it does not give the author of the commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the formatting yourself with the `--format` flag. E.g.:

```
git log --after="May 13" --before="May 15" --format="%H %aN> %s"
```